# Node.js Express can not use routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have created a simple Node.js application and I'm unable to set up any routes. I get the following error:

```
/Users/rexhin/Desktop/Exercise Files/02_03/finished/node/routes/index.js:5
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rexhin/Desktop/Exercise Files/02_03/finished/node/routes/index.js:5:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rexhin/Desktop/Exercise Files/02_03/finished/node/app.js:4:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
```

I don't know what the problem is here because I have included all the required modules.

My files are:

`app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

app.use(routes);
```

`/routes/index.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "ExpressHello",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Simple Express Application",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Rexhin",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^3.5.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to show us more code.  There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you show, therefore there must be a problem caused by other code that you have not shown us.  We need to see a larger context here.

Comment: show your package.json sir.

Comment: What version of Express do you have installed?  It should be Express 4.x.  In your project directory, you can run this cmd: `npm view express version` to see what version of Express you have installed.

Comment: The only way I can see this error could happen with the code you show is if `express.Router()` returns `undefined` and thus `router` becomes `undefined` and thus `router.get()` is an error because `router` is `undefined`.

Comment: Any chance you have a circular dependency where module A loads module B and module B loads module A?

Comment: @jfriend00 Thats all the code I have. `app.js` and `index.js` inside `routes folder` Express version is `4.15.0`

@Caspain check my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Should be.
/* GET home page. */

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
//this the editted code below, you forgot the route functor.
router.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

You have two way to route in express +4.0 either use the app instance from `var app = express()` which give you a hook to the main middle ware application(main) and can be accessed in this manner.

```
app.get('/example/a', function (req, res) {
res.send('Hello from A!')
});
```

or the Router instance from express.Router() which is for more a single localized route middle ware(not the main application).

which can be accessed in this manner.

```
var router = express.Router();
router.route('route').get(function(req,res){});
router.route('route').post(function(req,res){});
```

but you must return the router instance and attach to the main app middle ware by doing this,however because you returned a instance of express.Router() you need to qualify the middle ware route with a name qualifier..

```
app.use('some_route',router);
```

granted though this is valid.

```
// define the home page route
 router.get('/', function (req, res) {
 res.send('home page')
 })
```

just not recommended.

```
app.use(routes); //this line, i am guessing it is the imported module with the router.
```

try this.

```
app.use('/',routes);
```

Another reason your router instance could null, could be the path you used to retrieve the file. Check the absolute path once more,because looking at the error again indicates the router is non existent.

```
var routes = require('./routes/index'); is it valid ?
```

the problem was your version 3.5.1 upgrade. perform `npm uninstall express --save` then `npm install --save express`

Comment: Huhhh?  I don't understand what you're saying is the problem or the solution.

Comment: I'm not the OP.  I'm someone trying to understand what your suggestion is?  Please explain what you changed and why it fixed the problem.  Use words please.  `router.get()` is perfectly legit so I don't know why you're using `router.route()`.

Comment: check this edit, do you know why you getting the error sir?

Comment: check the edit and try again sir.well you said i was wrong, do you stand corrected?

Comment: if it worked , would you accept the answer.thank you. or u require a more in dept overview.

Comment: You seem to be guessing here.  `app.use(router);` is perfectly valid if you want the router to be top level routes.  And, `router.get()` is perfectly valid too and `app.use('some_route',router);` is NOT required.  There's lots of wrong info in this answer.

Comment: i know router.get() is valid, i did mention it.

Comment: But, for some unknown reason, you're telling the OP to switch to `router.route('route').get(function(req,res){});`.  Why?  You actually say that `router.get()` is not recommended.  That's just wrong.  I still don't see any explanation of what is wrong with the code in the original question.

Comment: the idea of express.Rotuer() is to seperate router logic,router.route('route').get(function(req,res){}); does it in a manner appropriate manner, however router.get() is not wrong , it's just a matter of choice and best practice followed by consistency. Are you gonna say i am guessing these words.

Comment: I'm saying that you're asking the OP to change something that does not matter.  And, you have not yet explained what is actually wrong with the code in the original question.

Comment: check your path of index file reference once more!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest version of express package? and can you share the contents of your package.json?

The express.Router method was added in express 4.x versions. 
If you're using an older version of express 3.x, then the express.Router method could be added by another module which might not be returning anything resulting in the **router** variable being undefined.

Comment: @Caspain I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, I wanted to contribute to the discussion and posting an answer seemed like the only way.  The error message seems to indicate that **router** is undefined. It does say that we're trying to access the property **get** of undefined.

Comment: oh make sense, TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined it is actually undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Express version in the `package.json` was `^3.5.1` but for some reason `npm` wasn't downloading `Express ^4.x.x` so the solution was to delete the node_modules folder, update Express version to `^4.15.0` and run npm install again.